# rsync: How to NOT apply wildcard excludes recursively

Tags: matlab, rsync

I'm using rsync to do a local backup of a Matlab model (end goal is a shell script to autobackup my key PhD files).

The model has layers of folders, and I want to exclude some wildcard matches on top level but not lower levels. Is this possible?

Example file structure:

```
/Model               % DO NOT WANT to sync *.mat files in this directory
/Model/Data/Greens   % WANT to sync *.mat files in this subdirectory
```

Example (simplified) code:

```
#!/bin/bash
rsync -a --exclude="*.mat" /Users/Me/MATLAB/Model /Volumes/KINGSTON/Backup
```

The example code excludes ALL *.mat files in ALL folder levels. How do I fix it to only apply the `'*.mat'` wildcard to the top folder?

TL;DR: Is there a way to apply rsync recursively to all subfolders, but apply a wildcard exclude to only the top-level folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `*.mat` is going to match all .mat files in your folder and all sub-directories. If you'd only like to ignore .mat files in the parent directory, you can add the `Model/` prefix to the `exclude` directive to only ignore .mat files in that folder

```
rsync -a --exclude="Model/*.mat" /Users/Me/MATLAB/Model /Volumes/KINGSTON/Backup
```

Alternately, if you want to include .mat files *only* in the `Model/Data/Greens` folder you can use the `--include` option in conjunction with the `--exclude` option

```
rsync -a --include="Model/Data/Greens/*.mat" --exclude="*.mat" /Users/Me/MATLAB/Model /Volumes/KINGSTON/Backup
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks.

Appreciate you giving both options.  The `--include` is useful for some things I want to do.